# Cannot import resource from inside JAR file

Tags: java, image, resources, icons

I am pretty new to java, and as such have been working on converting a instant messenger into java from autoit. Everything is working fine now, except after a complete re-code and restructure, the images included in the JAR no longer load properly. I've tried a couple solutions I've found here on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I tried deleting the image resources and re-adding them then changing  the relative paths in the code, as well as making sure correct CaSe is used.

```
public static Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/earth-icon.png"));
    public static Image iconTray = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/earth-icon16.png"));
    public static Image settingsIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/gnome_preferences_system.png"));
    public static Image fontIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/font-x-generic-icon.png"));
    public static Image mailIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/e_mail32.png"));
    public static Image profileIconMain = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/user_silhouette.png"));
    public static Image accountIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/vcard.png"));
    public static Image fileTransferIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/transfer_document32.png"));

    public static ImageIcon profileIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/user_silhouette.png"));
    public static ImageIcon onlineIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/buddy_online.png"));
    public static ImageIcon awayIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/buddy_away.png"));
    public static ImageIcon dndIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/buddy_dnd.png"));
    public static ImageIcon offlineIcon = new ImageIcon(Constants.class.getResource("/resources/icons/buddy_offline.png"));
    public static ImageIcon fontIcon2 = new ImageIcon(PersonalMessage.class.getResource("/resources/icons/font.png"));
    public static ImageIcon emoticonIcon = new ImageIcon(PersonalMessage.class.getResource("/resources/icons/regular_smile.png"));
    public static ImageIcon nudgeIcon = new ImageIcon(PersonalMessage.class.getResource("/resources/icons/nudge.png"));
    public static ImageIcon addIcon = new ImageIcon(PersonalMessage.class.getResource("/resources/icons/buddy_add.png"));
    public static ImageIcon transferIcon = new ImageIcon(PersonalMessage.class.getResource("/resources/icons/Transfer.png"));
```

Icons should be loaded into the gui, instead I get the following error

```
0xa5c9ba21dd6c5fb60de9ddc165f5917434387250Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at SIM.net.client.gui.loginFrame$2.actionPerformed(loginFrame.java:155)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImageFromHash(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getImage(Unknown Source)
    at SIM.net.client.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:65)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Also here is the structure of the resources package(s) https://imgur.com/ap5zXUD

Comment: also here's this https://imgur.com/a/aNGhHcY

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this by adding a "Resources" folder containing all my resources, then loading them directly from the root path (/)

Example:

```
public static Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Constants.class.getResource("/icons/earth-icon.png"));
```